# How early should I start learning my baby bedtime routine?

Tags: sleep, newborn, sleep-training

my baby is 2 month old. I want know when I should start "bedtime routine" ?
and also when make him sleep in his room ?
now he sleep next to me, is it correct to take him sleep on his bed or should I wait?

Comment: Hi and welcome to our community:) You've asked a two questions. Both of them have (more or less accurate) answers here already:
routine - http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/14776/how-important-is-a-settled-repeatable-routine-for-a-1-month-old
co-sleeping vs own bed - http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/197/is-there-any-scientific-evidence-in-favor-of-co-sleeping-with-children